# Aggregate root design and presentation layer

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I was wondering if how my presentation layer is structured could be a lead to design my aggregate roots.

Lets have an entity ProjectEntity and its related entity ProjectMemberEntity (1:M)

The page is structured as follows:

The top of the page is a form for ProjectEntity

Underneath the form is a grid that shows a list of ProjectMemberEntity.

If a new ProjectMember will be added, the user have to go to this page and click on the button "add new member" which is located in the header of the grid.also edit and delete has the same analogy.

I'm wondering if this behavior/'page structure' could be a hint for a aggregate root(projectentity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a hint for sure. But no more.

Better way to clarify kind of that entity relationship is to ask domain expert:

- does project member makes any sense without project?
- can member participate in multiple projects?

If those are answered positively, it's highly likely that You should model project member as an aggregate root itself. Otherwise - demote it as an entity that cannot live w/o a project.

---

Here is some code that might give You some ideas:

```
public class Project:Root{
 private List _members;
 public IEnumerable<Member> Members{get {return _members;}}
 public string Name{get;private set;}
 public bool IsFinished{get;private set;}
 public bool FinishedOn{get;private set;}
 public Project(string projectName){
  _members=new List<Member>();
  Name=projectName;
 }
 public Member AssignMember(string memberName){
  var member=new Member(memberName);
  _members.Add(member);
  return member;
 }
 public void UnassignMember(string memberName){
  var member=_members.First(m=>m.Name==memberName);
  if(!member.HasCompletedAllTasks())
   throw new Exception
    ("Cannot unassign member with incompleted tasks!");
  _members.Remove(member);
 }
 public void AssignTaskToMember(string taskName, string memberName){
  var member=_members.First(m=>m.Name==memberName);
  member.AssignTask(taskName);
 }
 public void MemberHasCompletedTask(Member member, Task task){
  EnsureListContains(_members,member);
  EnsureListContains(member.Tasks,task);
  task.MarkAsCompleted();
 }    
 public void FinishProject(){
  if(_members.Any(m=>!m.HasCompletedAllTasks()))
   throw new Exception
    ("Can't finish project before members have completed all their tasks.");
  IsFinished=true;
  FinishedOn=DateTime.Now;
 }
 private void EnsureListContains<T>(IList<T> lst, T itm){
  if(!lst.Contains(itm)) throw new Exception();
 }
}

public class Member:Entity{
 public string Name{get;private set;}
 private List<Task> _tasks;
 public IEnumerable<Task> Tasks{get{return _tasks;}}
 internal Member(string memberName){
  Name=name;
  _tasks=new List<Task>();
 }
 internal void AssignTask(string taskName){
  _tasks.Add(new Task(taskName));
 }
 public bool HasCompletedAllTasks(){
  return _tasks.All(t=>t.IsCompleted);
 }
 public Task GetNextAssignedTask(){
  return _tasks.Where(t=>!t.IsCompleted)
    .OrderBy(t=>t.AssignedOn).First();
 }
}

public class Task:Entity{
 public string Name{get; private set;}
 public bool IsCompleted{get; private set;}
 public DateTime CompletedOn{get; private set;}    
 public DateTime AssignedOn{get; private set;}
 internal Task(string name){
  Name=name;
  AssignedOn=DateTime.Now;
 }
 internal void MarkAsCompleted(){
  if(IsCompleted) throw new Exception
   ("Task is already completed!");
  IsCompleted=true;
  CompletedOn=DateTime.Now;
 }
}

public class App{
 public static void Main(){
  var project=new Project
    ("Question: Aggregate root design and presentation layer");
  var me=project.AssignMember("Arnis Lapsa");
  project.AssignTaskToMember("Try to help user137348","Lapsa");
  var currentTask=me.GetNextAssignedTask();
  //SpamStackOverflow();
  project.MemberHasCompletedTask(me,currentTask);
  if(me.HasCompletedAllTasks()) project.Finish();
  else throw new Exception("Enough for today...");
 }
}
```

Keep in mind that I got little knowledge of what Your business is about. This is just an improvisation. :)

Comment: what does it mean "does project member makes any sense without project?" ? There is a relationship created on the database level. So every project member has to have a parent project record. Or did you mean the situation that I have also a TaskEntity which have to be assigned to project member. I guess in this scenario the project member entity can be without the project,is that so ?

Comment: @user137348 when doing modeling, do not think about database (You will definitely have relationship at that level). think about what kind of problems Your application is trying to resolve. that's why it's called **domain** driven. if You don't need member to be independent, then it's an entity. You will always create project first and assign members to it (it makes no sense without project).

Comment: I see. But if a taskentity does reference a project member entity does this mean that the member entity is a aggregate root by itself and not a part of the projectentity ?

Comment: @user137348 no, not really. aggregate root is called so because it's a root http://bit.ly/dERZBI. branch (member in this case) does not become root because it has another branch below (task). advantage You gain from aggregate roots is that from outside You "talk" only with trees as a whole that are represented by roots. every state modification goes through root in that way drawing so called consistency boundary. will try to reflect that with code in my answer.

Comment: wow , thank you for the nice code sample.Its not exactly my domain model, but you had to little knowledge about it.But anyway, I know now much more about aggregate roots but I'm also still unable to design my certain domain :-)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to DDD, make sure you don't get analysis paralysis when trying to design your domain and aggregates. It happened to me. My project got literally STOPPED for a whole month because i wasn't enable to get my aggregates straight. And i am talking about a simple 3 database tables situation. User, Address and UserProfile.

The thing with DDD is that there is no such a thing like DONE THE RIGHT WAY. If you post the same question here with an interval of 3 months from each other, you will always get the "experts" giving you completely different answers in each question. Amis L. was kind enough to give you a solid simple example. Most people would copy and paste from Eric's books.

Do whatever floats your boat. At the end of the day, no matter how handcrafted your domain is, it's never RIGHT to the community. Just chill and enjoy coding.